# How to print only the first page in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report and would like to print only the first page regardless of the number of pages. That is if the report have five pages, i want only the first page to be returned.

I thought i could achieved that by section expert, however, my report have few sub reports. Please how to i return only one page regardless of the report size. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can select only page number 1 in print option?

Comment: @Siva , You mean print option in the crystal report? if so can you explain further pls?

Comment: I mean to say you can go to `file ---> print` select only one page there?..

Comment: In the crystal report sir? i can't locate that. In the crystal viewver, we have export button but does not show such options? where am i missing?

Comment: There was no mention of `Crystal Viewer` in question so I though you were talking about crystal report.. I am talking about crystal report not viewer

Comment: Yah i am talking about crystal report sir. Please can you elaborate where i can locate the print option ? dont seem to locate it yet , have being looking since u mentioned.

Comment: you have tabs right...`File, Edit..` in that file option you have `print`

Comment: I think you are talking about printing the report on the crystal report ? I am asking about how to set the report to display only the first two Tables in the crystal viewer sir. I want my customer to print the first two pages only.

Comment: Thats what I mean.. sorry to confuse you...

Comment: one option would be write a supress conditon for all sections as if `pagenumber>1 then true else false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Choose Section Expert
2. For very section set a `Suppress formula`
   [click `X-2` button in `Suppress (no drill-down)` line]
3. type this frmula `PageNumber >1`
   that means suppress this section if page number is greater than one.

That's all.

Comment: Its returning an empty page for a second page . I tried to supress the blanc page but it fails. I wrote this in the "New Page after" , under the section expert .                                `if(PageNumber = TotalPageCount) Then
    True
else
    False;`        . However it fails, I tried `NOT OnLastRecord` on each "Next Page After" of the report detals section. It fails also.Please have any sugggestion how i can get rid of the empty page?

Comment: Crystal has some issue on blank pages sometimes. Remove "keep together" on sections and groups if you have. Don't touch "new page after" and "new page before", just keep it unchecked. Touch blank page in preview and try to understand wich section are you in.

Comment: I think i recognized the section. Its the second section. Its the second section. "Keep together" ticked, "Free form-Placement" and "Supress blanc section " ticked. It displays the third page empty.

Comment: Untick "keep together". Is something changing?

Answer (score 0):

I know this late but it may be useful for someone in future by using Emanuele Greco above answer it is showing last page as blank to avoid last page as blank

Right Click on the Report Footer and choose Hide.It works for me